# Is there ant event or way to execute code while Unpublishing package in acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Is there ant event or way to execute code while Unpublishing package in acumatica.

I am using some acumatica screens in my package. If my customization package is published then acumtaica screen which we are using I am showing that screen only inside my workspace.

When I have unpublished my package i want that screen should be shown on related acutmatica workspace.

I have code to update workspace but i want the event or way how can i run that code while unpublishing my package.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a code script that inherits the object CustomizationPlugin which will allow you to run code after publish.  You'll have to write code to detect the state of your customization (i.e. published unpublished), before performing your action. see [this](https://www.acumatica.com/blog/acumatica-customization-plug-ins-and-testing/)